# Sampling from a distribution using a variable transformation

Tags: sampling, random-variable

I would like to draw samples from a pdf $f$. I can write $f$ as $f(x) = A g(y(x))$, where $A$ is a constant and $g$ is another pdf from which I can easily draw samples. Is there a way to first draw samples from $g$ (which is easy) and then transform these samples using the mentioned identity to create samples that follow the distribution $f$?

Comment: If $g$ is the pdf of $X$ then the pdf of a (one-one) transformation of $X$ has form $u'(x)g(u(x))$. So that does not look possible unless $y(x)$ is an affine function of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that is what I thought as well, since my $y(x)$ is non-affine, it does not seem possible, but I wanted to be certain.